# How to remove key value from map when keys are store in list in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, scala-collections

I have list of keys and map following:

> val keys = List("key1", "key2", "key5")
>
> Map("key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2, "key3" ->3, "key4" -> 4, "key5" -> 5)

I want to remove all of the keys that are in keys list.

I know I can iterator through keys list and check if map contains the key and if it does I can remove it.

Is there any easier way to do this without iterating keys list in which I just provide list of keys and all of keys that are presented in list are filtered out from map?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [--](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#--(xs:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce%5BA%5D):Repr) method

```
val keys = List("key1", "key2", "key5")
val map = Map("key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2, "key3" ->3, "key4" -> 4, "key5" -> 5)
map -- keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list of keys to a `Set` and then use `filterKeys` to select all keys that are not in that set:

```
val kSet = keys.toSet
map.filterKeys(!kSet.contains(_))
```

Comment: be careful with `filterKeys`: it is lazy, meaning that lookup will happen every time you access anything in the map. Might not matter very much in the particular case (because set lookup is quite quick), but still ... also there is additional memory overhead if there are lots of keys. Might want to tuck a `.toMap` at the end to force evaluation.